# kate konsole problem

Tags: command-line, kate, konsole

I have installed Konsole and I like to have Terminal window below my Kate, but it is not active even I have set Terminal Tool View on. 
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PXjV.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXDdH.png)

Comment: You haven't provided OS/release details, however the picture mentions a non-Ubuntu OS which is off-topic here (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: the OS  is Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Then why do you have "Deepin Screenshot" in image 1? And is Kate a snap? And what about Konsole?

Comment: I used "Deepin Screenshot" to take screen shot image from the Kate window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was two Kate application in my Ubuntu Software Center, I have installed first one, remove it and installed the last Kate in the list, SOLVED THE PROBLEM.

[Kate Apps in my software center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMake.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 19.10, kate version 19.04.3-0ubuntu2.1 : add konsole

1. Settings > Configure Kate > Plugins : tick "Terminal Tool Wiew" > Apply
2. Tools : tick "Focus Terminal"

Comment: Suggest : Reset kate to default → Delete `~.config/{katerc, kateschemarc}` and redo the "konsole settings".